# Drupal ckeditor not supports some html tags

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor in Drupal.

I have tried to add the following code in the block content using ckeditor

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/profile.png" alt="">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <span class="name">Start Bootstrap</span>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <span class="skills">Web Developer - Graphic Artist - User Experience Designer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

But the above code displaying like this

```
<header></header>
```

Inside contents are not displaying. I don't know what is happening inside. Did anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the cleanup and output settings of both Drupal and CKEditor. The fastest and most effective way to achieve this is by creating a new input format, for example "HTML" via /admin/config/content/formats/add with all cleanup processing disabled. This way, your HTML input = HTML output.

**Sidenote: Make sure your profile/the admin profile/role is the only role that is able to use it so only trusted users have access to this text-format.**